# getopts does not seem to work

Tags: bash, getopts

I am trying to run the following script using `getopts` to parse the options but it does not seem to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
echo $@
while getopts "rf" opt
do
  case "${opt}" in
    r)
        ropt=${OPTARG}
        ;;
    f)
        fopt=${OPTARG}
        ;;
  esac
done

shift $((OPTIND -1))

echo $fopt $ropt
```

The output I get is:

```
$ ./myscript.sh -f opt2 -r opt1
+ echo -f opt2 -r opt1
-f opt2 -r opt1
+ getopts rf opt
+ case "${opt}" in
+ fopt=
+ getopts rf opt
+ shift 1
+ echo

+ set +x
```

Do you have any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You expect your options to take option-arguments, but you don't let `getopts` know about this.

You should use

```
while getopts "r:f:" opt; do ...; done
```

i.e., each option that takes an argument should have `:` after it in the argument string to `getopts`.

You'll probably also want a *default* `case` branch at the end to handle invalid options:

```
 *) usage >&2
    exit 1
```

(the error message (about invalid option or missing option argument) will be displayed by `getopts` itself, `usage` is expected to be a function that you will have defined that prints a short help message to standard output).

Also, don't forget to double quote *all* expansions, even `$(( OPTIND - 1 ))`.

Related to that last point:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)

Comment: Why double quote `$((OPTIND -1))`? Isn't the result of an arithmetic expression always a number?

Comment: @user000001 Yes, and `$IFS` may include digits. which means that the number could be split into multiple words/numbers.  Test with `n=123; ( IFS=13; echo $n )`.

Comment: Thant's interesting, never thought of that case

Comment: @user000001 Very few does.  Fortunately, _most_ shells reset `IFS` for each new shell invocation. `dash` does not, so potentially one could `export IFS=0123456789` before running a `/bin/sh` shell script on Unices where `sh` is `dash` just to see in what way it breaks.

Comment: I more benign example might be someone setting `IFS=-` to split something on dashes, and then not resetting it, causing the leading minus sign to be lost. Arguably the bug would be caused by not resetting the original value of `IFS` and not by the lack of quotes, but I guess it never hurts to program defensively.